# Sales Calculator Using Loops, Tuples, Lists, Dictionaries, Etc

Tags: python

I am trying to make a sales calculator that shows different things such as what was the maximum sale for the week and which day was it, what was the minimum sale for the week and which day was it, what is the total amount of sales of all days added together, average sales for the week, and a sales commission of 0$ for less than 100$ made, 25$ for sales between $100 and 250$, 30$ for sales between $250 and $500, and 40$ for sales over 500$.

I've tried different ways of calculating the average but can't get it to work and i'm not sure how to work in the sales commission as well as linking the min and max to the day of the week they occur on.

This is what I currently:

```
print ("Sales Calculator Program")

print ('\n')


expenses = []
for day_number in range (1, 5 + 1):
    while True:
        user_input = float(input(f"Enter sales for day {day_number}\n> "))
        if user_input >= 0:
            expenses.append(user_input)
            break
        else:
            print(f"Amount may not be negative. Try again:")


print ('\n')       

average = average(expenses)
finalExpenses = sum(expenses)


print ("Total weekly sales were $" +str(finalExpenses))
print ("Average of the sales is $" +str(average))
```

This is what i'm trying to get it to look like:

```
Enter sales for day 1: 10.22 (User input)
Enter sales for day 2: 4.12 (User input)
Enter sales for day 3: 3.78 (User input)
Enter sales for day 4: 6.82 (User input)
Enter sales for day 5: 22.45 (User input)

Maximum sales was on Friday which is $22.45
Minimum sales was on Wednesday which is $3.78
Total weekly sales were $47.39
Average of the sales is $9.48
Sales too low for commission must earn more than $100
```

Thank you!

Comment: For min and max. The built in min and max will be too much work (they return the value, not the index in the list which you need to work out which day it is), just write your own that returns the index in the list.

Comment: @Paul Rooney I got everything working besides it being able to return the day of the week. I know that I need it to match up with 1 being monday, 2 being tuesday, 3 being wednesday, 4 being thursday and 5 being friday but i'm not sure how to do it i've been trying for the past few hours

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Sales Calculator Program")

print ('\n')


expenses = []
for day_number in range (1, 5 + 1):
    while True:
        user_input = float(input(f"Enter sales for day {day_number}\n> "))
        if user_input >= 0:
            expenses.append((day_number,user_input))
            break
        else:
            print(f"Amount may not be negative. Try again:")


print ('\n')       
max = max(expenses, key=lambda x: x[1])
min = min(expenses, key=lambda x: x[1])
total = sum(map(lambda x: int(x[1]), expenses))    
average = total/len(expenses)


for item in expenses :
    if item[0] == 1:
       Monday ...
```

For the rest you should try urself now you can use max min sum etc ... try to know more about some builtin functions before you ask here :))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
print ("Sales Calculator Program")

print ('\n')

expenses = []
for day in range(1, 6):
    while True:
        sales = float(input(f"Enter sales for day {day}\n> "))
        if sales >= 0:
            expenses.append((sales, day))
            break
        else:
            print(f"Amount may not be negative. Try again:")

print ('\n')       

days = ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

maxval = max(expenses, key=lambda x: x[0]) # could also use operator.itemgetter
minval = min(expenses, key=lambda x: x[0])

total = sum(e[0] for e in expenses)
average = total / len(expenses)

print('Maximum sales was on %s which is $%.2f' % (days[maxval[1]], maxval[0]))
print('Minimum sales was on %s which is $%.2f' % (days[minval[1]], minval[0]))

print ("Total weekly sales were $%.2f" % total)
print ("Average of the sales is $%.2f" % (average))
if total < 100.0:
    print('Sales too low for commission must earn more than $100')
```

Store the daily value with the day index in a tuple. You can then use `max` or `min` with a key function to pick out element 0 as the one to use in the calculation of max/min. When you come to print it the second element in the tuple can be used to index into the `days` array to get the day name.

The calculation of the mean average should be pretty self explanatory.

Note that floating point numbers are not suitable for storing monetary values in any application that needs to be correct. Instead store values in cent/pence or use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html).